# Regex - split/separate after 2 occurrences of the separator

Tags: regex, separator

I need to split `aaa|aaa|aaa/bbb|bbb|bbb`
into `aaa|aaa|aaa` and `bbb|bbb|bbb`.

Easy, just split based on the `/`.

But no, I can also have this scenario:

```
aaa|aa/a|aaa/bbb|bb/b|bbb
```

So I need to split using the `/` character but only after 2 occurrences of the `|` character.

Any ideas???

Comment: solved - [^/].*?\|.*?\|.*?(?=/|$)

Comment: You only have separators, not delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any particular language?  How about something like this?

```
(.*\|.*\|.*)\/(.*)
```

Comment: That pattern will probably run into some trouble with the greedy quantifiers. `.*?` might be a better way to go, or `[^|]*` to include anything _except_ pipes.

Comment: C# - actually found the answer 

[^/].*?\|.*?\|.*?(?=/|$)